# convert single column to hierarchical column from csv

Tags: python, pandas

When I import a csv file that has a single column consisting of states and cities such as:

```
ALABAMA
NaN
Birmingham
Montgomery
Huntsville
NaN
CALIFORNIA
NaN
Los Angeles
San Diego
Fresno
NaN
```

My question is, how can I convert this into two hierarchical columns so that it would look more like the following:

```
ALABAMA    Birmingham
           Montgomery
           Huntsville
CALIFORNIA Los Angeles
           San Diego
           Fresno
```

I tried creating an emtpy series and populate it with the value from each row from the city column with the intention of importing the series as an extra column but I've been unable to get it to work.

My code:

```
i = 0
numcol = []
for STATE in city_state_df['citystate']:
    if STATE == '':        
        numcol.append(STATE_df['citystate'][i])
        i += 1
    elif STATE != '': 
        numcol.append(STATE_df['citystate'][i])
        i += 1
numcol
```

Comment: What is your logic?  All caps are states?  The row following a NaN?  The row before NaN?

Comment: Yes, in the original single column file, states are in caps and the rows before and after each state is empty (displays as NaN) Also I should mention that the single column file is called cityState and I would like it as two columns headed as city and state respectively. I think the state columns might need to be repeated for each city column.

Comment: I'm not sure pandas can do this. If it were me I'd write a python script to reformat the file to look like:

    ALABAMA,    Birmingham \n
    ALABAMA,    Montgomery \n 
    CALIFORNIA, Los Angeles \n

then read that in with pandas read_csv.

Answer (score 1):

read the data into a pandas DataFrame

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
```

Here, I'm assuming the column is called `place`.

Use `groupby` to group all rows that start with a state (all-caps) until the next state, pick the first `place` for each group (the state) and assign it to a new column in the data frame

```
df['state'] = df.groupby(df.place.str.isupper().cumsum()).place.transform('first')
```

Then remove rows where the `place` is `null` or `place == state`

```
df[pd.notnull(df.place) & (df.place != df.state)]
outputs:
          place       state
2    Birmingham     ALABAMA
3    Montgomery     ALABAMA
4    Huntsville     ALABAMA
8   Los Angeles  CALIFORNIA
9     San Diego  CALIFORNIA
10       Fresno  CALIFORNIA
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Another (maybe less pythonic solution) can be this:

```
city_state_df = pd.DataFrame({'citystate' :['ALABAMA', np.NaN, 'Birmingham', 'Huntsville', np.NaN,'CALIFORNIA',np.NaN, 'Los Angeles','San Diego',np.NaN]})

     citystate
0      ALABAMA
1          NaN
2   Birmingham
3   Huntsville
4          NaN
5   CALIFORNIA
6          NaN
7  Los Angeles
8    San Diego
9          NaN
```

Copy the column and delete the rows that are not upper case in the first column and the one that are uppercase in the second one. Use `bfill` in the first and delete the rows that are `null`.In the end rename the columns

```
city_state_df['city'] = city_state_df['citystate']
city_state_df = city_state_df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
city_state_df['citystate'] = city_state_df['citystate'].apply(lambda x: x if x.isupper() else np.NaN).ffill()
city_state_df['city'] = city_state_df['city'].apply(lambda x: np.NaN if x.isupper() else x)
city_state_df = city_state_df.replace('', np.NaN, regex=True).dropna(subset=['city'])
city_state_df.columns = ['state', 'city']
```

Output:

```
        state         city
2     ALABAMA   Birmingham
3     ALABAMA   Huntsville
7  CALIFORNIA  Los Angeles
8  CALIFORNIA    San Diego
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, this is an alternative I may consider.